# Python requests time out on a linux machine but not on windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, redis, python-requests

So I wrote a python script that iterates over a list of URLs and records the time it takes to get a response. Some of these ULRs can take upwards of a minute to respond, which is expected (expensive API calls) the first time they are called, but are practically instantaneous the second time (redis cache).

When I run the script on my windows machine, it works as expected for all URLs.

On my Linux server it runs as expected until it hits an URL that takes upwards of about 30 seconds to respond. At that point the call to `requests.get(url, timeout=600)` does not return until the 10 minute timeout is reached and then comes back with a "Read Timeout". Calling the same URL again afterwards results in a fast, successfull request, because the response has now been cached in redis. (So the request must have finished on the server providing the API.)

I would be thankful for any ideas as to what might be causing this weird behavior.

Comment: What is output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries `?

Comment: @Andersson At this point in time the output is `6` everything has been cached for a while, so the problem hasn't come up recently. (And I am somwwhat reluctant to invalidate the cache.)
What kind of output would I be looking for? What could be learned from that?

Comment: This was just an assumption regarding http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout. But `6` seem to be ok.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be worth a try though. Before I run it the next time, I'll try setting it to 9 or something and see what happens. I'll report back.

Comment: Update: Setting `tcp_syn_retries` to 9 did not help the situation.

Comment: Final update from my side on this issue: We were never able to solve the problem. Most likely it had something to do with the VPN the linux server was part of. Our "solution" was to move script execution to a different machine.